# Not able to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from Nuget Package Manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in my ASP.NET Core Web API project. But I get an error when I try to install:

> Error     Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'RabbitMQ'.
>
> Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions. Install/reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 3.1.0 directly to project
>   RabbitMQ to resolve this issue.   RabbitMQ ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions (>= 3.1.0)   RabbitMQ ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && <
>   2.2.0).   RabbitMQ    P:\Users\vivek.nuna\RabbitMQ\RabbitMQ\RabbitMQ\RabbitMQ.csproj  1

I have tried restarting VS, but it does not help.

VS 2017 version 15.8.6

CS Proj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="5.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Although I am able to install it in .Net Core console application the same machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.11 version

Comment: Could you explain why?